# Get id's of related entities during query in Doctrine2?

Tags: doctrine-orm, entity-relationship

I have the following query:

```
    $qb = $this->em->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select(array('p','c' ,'sc'))
            ->from('Project\Entity\Product', 'p')
            ->innerJoin("p.category", "c")
            ->innerJoin("p.subcategory", "sc")
            ->where("p.available != 0")
            ->orderBy("p.create_date")
            ->addOrderBy("p.id")
            ->setMaxResults($limit);
```

In a result I would like to get only Products with id's of related entities (category and subcategory).

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid you can't do that.
Either you use [fetch joins](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.1/en/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#joins) and obtain fully loaded objects or load just the object and obtain an uninitialized collection (which requires one more query to be initialized).